# generating a horizontal table of data generated from ajax/json

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

so currenly my code gets a list of ids from localstorage and compares them against ids in a json file, and if they match then it will display the data that matches in a table.

my table at the moment is just stacking and im unsure of how to properlly form it.

heres an image of two tables ive made, first one is made with html(is what im aiming for), second one is the result of my code 
[image]

code:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    $(".compareAll").click(function(e) {
console.log("click");
        //alert("this works");
       window.location.href = 'selection.html';
           })
        var CollectGameIds= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedGameIds")); 
    console.log(CollectGameIds);
    $.getJSON("data/games.json", (newData) => {


    var selectedGames = newData.filter(function(game){
            //console.log(game.Name);
                if(CollectGameIds.indexOf(game.ID)!==-1){
                    console.log("true");
                    console.log(game.Name);
                    for (var i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {

                    }

                  document.getElementById("itemID").innerHTML += `<table class='table table-hover'>
  <thead>
  <tr>
        <th>  ${game.Name} </th>

  </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td> ${game.RetailPrice} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>`;   

                } else {
                console.log("false");
                }
            })


            console.log(selectedGames);
    //})


        })

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently writing a new table for each game result. You are providing no information about JSON structure, so I am assuming this is like the following:

```
[
    { ID: 1, Name: "one", RetailPrice: 12.99 },
    { ID: 2, Name: "two", RetailPrice: 12.99 },
    ...
]
```

The correct parsing should evaluate the array twice, and then build a single row with all the results:

```
$.getJSON("data/games.json", (newData) => {

    var html = '<table class="table table-hover>';
    html += '<thead><tr>';

    for (var game of newData) {
        if (CollectGameIds.indexOf(game.ID) !== -1)
            html += '<td>' + game.Name + '</td>';
    }

    html += '</tr></thead>';
    html += '<tbody><tr>';

    for (var game of newData) {
        if (CollectGameIds.indexOf(game.ID) !== -1)
            html += '<td>' + game.RetailPrice + '</td>';
    }

    html += '</tr></tbody>';
    html += '</table>';

    $("#itemID").html(html);

})
```

This code is not tested, and it can be further optimized, but should work. Please let me know.

Comment: the structure is fine, but how the code works wont be suitable in my case, is there another way to go about it?

Comment: Please be more specific in what do you mean. It's not very clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: well for some reason, your code doesnt produce anything(though it does look like it works) im just trying to produce the first table in the image i displayed

Comment: You have to adapt it to your real code. I'm just giving a hint, on how it could be done, but it's untested and it's likely not working as is. Maybe some variable name is changed? The console prints something?

Comment: oh yeah i know, i adapted and updated it to my code, console doesnt print anything nor errors, debugger doesnt show anything so im a little confused haha

Comment: found out why, the for in loop was a bad idea, for of seems to have fixed it!